# Where Should Collision Detection Code Be?

Tags: ruby, collision-detection, hittest

I'm writing a pong game and I have a ball class that has velocity x, y, positions and all that stuff that every frame is updated by calling @ball.update, this moves the ball forward by its x_vel and Y_vel etc. My question is Should my collision code be in the loop or in the update method of the ball class? Or should it all be in the loop and the ball should not have any control of its position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collision detection should not be done in you ball class because it would require the knowledge of all other objects in your game.

Imagine a shooter with many objects and think about what happens if each object would try to calculate the collision on it's own.

There should be a dedicated class that cares about collision detection. This class is notified if any of its supervised objects changed its position. Then it checks for collision and notifies all abjects (not only 2 :) that have a collsion.

Have fun... :)

Answer (score 2):

A Ball class like you described is indeed a good idea.  That way you can replicate it if, like in some "breakout" games, you ever want to spawn two or more balls -- or if you want to re-use that code in another game.  You can also have a Paddle class with similar X,Y coordinates (or derive both Ball and Paddle from a "ScreenObject" class if they turn out to share many such similar members).  Paddle can read a shared variable that gets updated by a thread/event receiving user input.

Simple collisions, such as against walls, can be done in your Ball class based on globally accessible values like the screen dimension extents.  Your Update routine can simply reverse one velocity component when that particular wall is hit.  You can define and set a delegate/callback in the Ball class to play a sound when the ball bounces.  Similarly, Paddle's Update can check the screen size so you can't move the paddle off-screen.

Like TottiW recommended, collision between objects is best done in a parent "manager" class that owns all the objects or has access to their X,Y members or bounding boxes.  This is good object-oriented design.  Ball and Paddle shouldn't have access to each other's X,Y positions! ...but the manager does.  It can also eliminate redundant collision checks.  If object A checks to collide with object B, B shouldn't have to subsequently check for collision with A.  So really all your manager class needs to do is, for each Paddle, check each Ball's position.  This can be further simplified since a Paddle might only move in one direction, say horizontally, at a fixed Y position.  Thus your first check can immediately eliminate any Ball.Y < Paddle.Y, for simplistic example (depending on Y's direction).

For games with lots of objects, you don't want to collison-detect every one, just the nearest ones.  In that case, the "manager" becomes more of a "scene manager" which keeps linked lists of objects in both X and Y directions.  As objects move past other objects, they exchange pointers in the lists, so the lists always stay sorted.  That way, for any given object, we know the objects immediately to the left/right/above/below, so we need only do collision checks against those... saving lots of time and making your game run with maximum speed.  Maybe you're not to this point, though!

Good luck and like the others have said, have fun with it!

Comment: Thanks, these comments have been very useful!

Answer (score 1):

For pong simple matrix operations should be sufficient. A ball class is not needed if there is only one and you use it only for holding a tuple.